# kendo ui show AutoComplete dropdown with given item count

Tags: autocomplete, kendo-ui

Is there anyway to make the kendo AutoComplete show dropdown with given item count? eg: When the items less than 50, show the dropdown, and when larger, don't show the dropdown or show a warning field.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the kendo-ui autocomplete [doc](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/autocomplete), the key is to recognize that if [`dataSource`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/autocomplete#configuration-dataSource) is empty, the dropdown will not show up.

Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivan_sim/okg6wsau/) to see if it does what you want.

1. The dropdown will appear if `limit` is set to a number higher than the size of the `data` array.
2. Otherwise, the dropdown will not appear, and the placeholder shows a warning message.